# Class name that is already a macro

Tags: c++, class, macros

I have the following code :

```
class MessageBox
{
    public:
        MessageBox();
};
```

But the problem is that `MessageBox` is a os-specific macro in my case and it causes problems.
I tried `#define MyMacro MessageBox`, then `#undef MessageBox` and re-define it later, but that only works inside the header, and so when i try to create an object of type `MessageBox` in a source file, it does not work.

Comment: Use a different name for your class that doesn't conflict with existing names?

Comment: What is the actual macro name?

Comment: "Is there any solution to this problem?" use proper UPPERCASE macros and not use them for not macros.

Comment: @Slava It is an os-specific macro, I can not choose the way it is written...

Comment: Then do not use that macro and do not include that header. Let me guess that macro is `min` or `max` ?

Comment: Well I would really like to have this name for the class, and I need to use the macro, but of course if there is no solution I will change the class name.

Comment: The macro name is `MessageBox`

Comment: What OS? Where do you have to use that macro?

Comment: Don't include `Windows.h` in the header, move it to the cpp file containing the implementation of `MessageBox`. `#undef MessageBox` within the cpp file after including `Windows.h` and call `MessageBoxA/W` explicitly within your code. But you may run into other problems doing this ...

Comment: In Windows programming avoid the Windows API function names like `MessageBox`, since they're generally defined as macros by `<windows.h>`. Make sure to define `NOMINMAX` before including that header, to avoid that it defines `min` and `max` as macros.

Comment: You can use some prefix/suffix to distinguish class name to indicate that it is a type name. For example `t_MessageBox`.

Comment: You should post a **complete example that reproduces the problem**. It's very unclear to me how you can have a problem at all. Voted to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `MessageBox` is an essential WinAPI macro that will alter class name if `<Windows.h>` is included somewhere.

Comment: @VTT: It will alter that name in the same way everywhere, so no problem. I start to think that the only problem here is one explicitly introduced by the OP, by `#undef`-ing `MessageBox`. If so then the cure is simply to not do anything (or to also include `<windows.h>` in the implementation file).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf No, it won't alter it everywhere. If some translation unit has `#include "message_box.h" #include <Windows.h>` then it would be broken. Alternatively if some translation unit has just `#include "message_box.h"` and another has `#include <Windows.h> #include "message_box.h"` then class will be duplicated with different names. Writing `undef` will potentially break existing `MessageBox` function calls.

Comment: @VTT: Oh, you're assuming that `<windows.h>` is not included in the header. I didn't think of that (other than the general observation that the example is very incomplete; I voted to close because of that). Well then the cure is to remove the `#undef`-ing and include `<windows.h>`. I usually do that via a wrapper that can be overridden via the compiler's include path.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of you class matches a macro that you really can't change, then you'll have to change the name of your class.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a header which would be added by rest of headers or sources of your project which need it instead of system header and create a thin wrapper function:

```
#include <system_header.h>

inline void myMessageBox( ... )
{
    MessageBox( ... );
}

#undef MessageBox
```

it is difficult to say how to pass parameters without further details of that macro.

Comment: The macro is usually defined as `MessageBoxW`. In the case of legacy code, or students, or people that try to support old versions of Windows that their tools can't generate executables for, it can be defined as `MessageBoxA`. It beats me how the OP's problem can manifest.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf have no idea, fortunately I do not have to work win MS match, anyway this solution should work.

Comment: @Slava I seem to be a little unclear on this, but if the macro is undefined, then wouldn't the MessageBox call inside myMessageBox try to access a macro that doesn't exist at runtime? (Assuming that preprocessor statements are evaluated before compilation).

Comment: @ArnavBorborah macros do not exist at runtime, they do not even exist during compilation. So preprocessor will replace body of myMessageBox with macro and the process `#undef` directive. You can check by looking into preprocessed file

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying! One more question: Why wouldn't the following work? `#define myMessageBox MessageBox (\n) #undef MessageBox`. Wouldn't the same logic apply here?  @Slava

Comment: @ArnavBorborah you cannot rename macro, difference is that in my solution macro is replaced by inline function which does not require preprocessor anymore. Your solution would not work.

Comment: Ah I see, Thank you very much.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah `MessageBox` in your `#define` wouldn't be expanded until `myMessageBox` is actually *used*, at which point `MessageBox` would be already undefined.

Comment: I do_not_use CamelCase. Leave that to the MicroSoft code of old. Actually, I do not use MS stuff either.  I use STL and wxWidgets.